# How to run a xcode project downloaded from github without installing cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, github, terminal, cocoapods

Can we run an Xcode project downloaded from github without installing Cocoa Pods?
If not, can we use some platform other than Github?

Every time we download an Xcode project from Github, we need to install the pods in the terminal and after that, we are ready to go. We can run and see the project on `.xcworkspace` file.

```
user$ cd /directory path

user$ pod install
```

I really don't know if it is even possible to do or not.

Comment: This is an expected behavior to avoid committing pod files, which are already versioned. With Xcode 11, you will be able to use Swift Package Manager, hopefully this will be easier to use

Comment: The answer is **NO** you need to download the dependencies along with the project.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Pods shouldn't be uploaded to `github` . The pod files are being ignored by .gitignore.

**Following process is not a recommended process**

If you want your pod files uploaded to github, open the `.gitignore` file and remove `Pods/` line. `.gitignore` ignores the files or directory that are included in your project.

After saving `.gitignore` and run `git status` in the terminal you will find the pods ready to be committed.